# How to fill missing times with dummy values?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have quite an urgent question. I have data (concentration) which was logged every minute. However, when I download my data there are some times (e.g. 1 or 2 minutes) in between missing.

For 24h I would have 1440 rows of results but I get less. Now I was trying to use lookup, if and combined index-match functions to fill out those missing results with dummy values or text saying "NA". But it doesn't work out and I can't find what I do wrong.

Could you give me a top on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the entire range where your data are. 
   I don't understand all of what you're saying,
   but I guess this would be the 1440 cells in a column
   (or more, if you have multiple days' data).
2. Do "Go To Special...".  You can get to this
   from the "Home" tab, "Editing" panel, "Find & Select" button,
   or by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and clicking on "Special...".
3. Click on "Blanks" and "OK". 
   The blank cells in your range should now be selected.
4. Type the value that you want (e.g., `#N/A`)
   and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd><sup>1</sup>.
   ________
   <sup>1</sup> ***Not*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.